How to include the month(date) in the echo statement in unix
I intend to print out boy+month+i...The issue seems to be with the date month variable. I tried with running and the month date seems to be neglected.I know the month date can be fixed manually, but I would like to know thisway..
a='boy'
icmonth= date +"%m" #print out month number example 09
for((i=0;i<=31;i++))
do
echo "$a$icmonth$i"
done

Expected Output
boy091
boy092

Curren Output
boy1
boy2


That's still not the output. You should have one line containing a number and then 32 lines starting with boy followed by a number.

Please replace the "shell" tag with the tag of the shell you actually target. Please read the description of that tag (and that of those two others I removed) for further info.

see: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_19_06_03

Perhaps it's just an artifact of the display, but your question shows that you are executing icmonth= date +"%m", which is not an assignment of the variable icmonth in the current shell.  Is that actually the command you are running?

The command:
icmonth= date +"%m" #print out month number example 09

is not an assignment of the variable icmonth in the current shell. In general, when you write something like:
var1=value var2=value cmd

the cmd is executed with var1 and var2 set in its environment, but var1 and var2 are not set or modified in the current shell.  When you execute icmonth= date ...., you are setting icmonth to the empty string in the environment of date.  Since date does not care about the environment variable icmonth, that command is exactly the same as if you had just executed date +"%m" (which, incidentally, is the same as date +%m and date "+"%m and date "+%"m and date +\%m, and date '+'%"m", and even d"at"e '+'%m, ad nauseum)
If you want to make the assignment in the current shell, try:
icmonth=$(date +%m)


The icmonth in your currently command encounters incorrect assignment, which causes the command to not be assigned correctly to the variable.
icmonth= date +"%m" #print out month number example 09

Just make sure there is no space between icmonth= and the date command.
#!/bin/bash

a='boy'
icmonth=$(date +"%m")

for((i=0;i<=31;i++))
do
echo "$a$icmonth$i"
done

